# Null entering as 0 in the below query

Tags: mysql, sql, case

1. In the below query I am saving into data base an array from multiple select2 options.
2. Here i have a database table participants with event_id(int, not null), user_id(int, null), p_mail(varchar, null).
3. When I pass proper id which is in users the data gets saved properly and null will be displayed in p_email column.
4. But when i pass some varchar values through array, the user_id is saved as 0 which should be NULL and Null is stored in p_email which should store the values.

   ```
   foreach($resources as $r) {
       global $response;
       $sql = "INSERT INTO participants(event_id, user_id, p_email)
                   SELECT $response,
                          CASE 
                            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * from users where id = '$r') THEN 
                               '$r'
                            ELSE NULL
                          END,
                          CASE 
                            WHEN  EXISTS (SELECT * from users where id = '$r') THEN 
                              NULL
                            ELSE '$r'
                          END
                   FROM users  WHERE id = 1;";
       $query_result = $conn->query($sql) or die("Failed".$sql);
   ```
5. this is expected where it int is passed it should be stored in user_id column if id exists otherwise if its varchar it should be stored in p_email.
   [image]
6. Present if I store a varchar which is not in users after checking instead of storing it in p_email. it stores null in p_email and 0 in user_id.

Comment: the SQL code really look suspect to possible SQL injection attacks.

Comment: can u suggest better solution please?

Comment: For a quick fix, try removing the single quotes around `$r`, and then _don't_ pass in non numeric data.  If you want a negative test case, use some `id` which you know doesn't exist, e.g. `999999`.

Comment: "when i pass some varchar values" and the values cannot be converted to a number then MySQL converts it to 0 instead of NULL.

Comment: @SalmanA how can i avoid that? any ideas please

Comment: Post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: @SalmanA u can check image and point 5 and 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared this issue by using LIKE instead of '=' in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that the `id` column is numeric.  In the first test, you are presumably passing some legitimate numerical string `id`, such as `'123'`.  MySQL has no issue internally converting between `'123'`, the string, and `123`, the number.  However, in your second test, you are passing something like `abc`.  In this case, MySQL appears to be converting that to a numeric value of `0`.  Also, assuming the `id` zero does exist, you would see `NULL` in your email column as well.

So, I think the correction here is to just bind numbers to your insert query, assuming the `id` column is really numeric.

And, you should read about using prepared statements in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually i have  id 0 in my users.

Comment: @RohitGowda I misspoke.  If `id` zero does exist, then after the forced conversion of text to numeric, you'd get `NULL` as the email.

Comment: Thank you very much i'll try to bind numbers to insert query and check.